# Deleting a user account and all files / directories

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, rmdir

I am making a intranet customer manager in php and have put together the following to remove the customer account and the directory / files associated with that account. The problem I am having is when you click delete it is deleting the user from the MYSQL DB just fine, but for some reason isn't removing the directory, what makes it worse is it isn't displaying any errors either, its just working :-S .

```
    <?php
    $cfid = $_GET['token'];

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer WHERE cf_id = $cfid") or die(mysql_error());

    $dir = '/customer-files/$cfid/';

    //Delete folder function
    function deleteDirectory($dir) {
        if (!file_exists($dir)) return true;
        if (!is_dir($dir) || is_link($dir)) return unlink($dir);
            foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
                if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') continue;
                if (!deleteDirectory($dir . "/" . $item)) {
                    chmod($dir . "/" . $item, 0777);
                    if (!deleteDirectory($dir . "/" . $item)) return false;
                };
            }
            return rmdir($dir);
        }


    ?>
```

Comment: Add this to the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see if any errors/warnings are thrown.

Comment: If I add the error reporting I get twice at the top of the page : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: In what line? What what does the line contain?

Answer (score 3):

This won't work.

```
$dir = '/customer-files/$cfid/';
```

It has to be double quotes

```
$dir = "/customer-files/$cfid/";
```

Read more about it here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Note - This is actually assuming that you call the method `deleteDirectory($dir)` at some point.

Also, I suggest you read up on SQL injection (if you haven't already). Your script can be broken and the DB harmed quite easily with the current setup.

And, use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) if not [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). It is recommended that you do not use the old mysql library.

Comment: SQL injection isnt an issue on this by the way, as its running on a stand alone pc not connected to the internet, its just for use in a shop.

Comment: Do a var_dump of `$dir`. Type it into your explorer / console to see if the path is correct.

Comment: if I do var_dump($dir); I get nothing ?

Comment: If you did this inside the `deleteDirectory()` method, then that means the place you're calling is not passing in the correct variable or it's empty. Have a look at the place where the path is constructed and confirm that the path is created properly.

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have error displaying turned on in php config.

Second check if your server has permissions to delete this folder and files inside it. If you can't execute rmdir($dir) because of missing permissions chmod($dir . "/" . $item, 0777); will probably also fail.

Comment: I can remove files as I have had another script work doing that, its just this one doesnt seem to want to do much apart from delete the user from thE db.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in the end I got it working using the following >>

```
    <?php
    $cfid = $_GET['token'];

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM rok5g_chronoforms_data_editcustomer WHERE cf_id = $cfid") or die(mysql_error());



    define('PATH', "./customer-files/$cfid/");

    function destroy($dir) {
        $mydir = opendir($dir);
        while(false !== ($file = readdir($mydir))) {
            if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                chmod($dir.$file, 0777);
                if(is_dir($dir.$file)) {
                    chdir('.');
                    destroy($dir.$file.'/');
                    rmdir($dir.$file) or DIE("couldn't delete $dir$file<br />");
                }
                else
                    unlink($dir.$file) or DIE("couldn't delete $dir$file<br />");
            }
        }
        closedir($mydir);
    rmdir("$dir");
    }
    destroy(PATH);
    echo 'all done.';



    ?>
```